# Issue while Enabling Cloud Translation API in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-translate

I am trying to Enable Cloud Translation API and my project is also linked with valid Billing Account Still i am facing the issue.
[image]

Comment: 1) What are the warnings attached to the first two billing accounts? Do you have a payment issue? 2) The message mentions region. What are the details regarding the region? Edit your post with details and context.